# Get the node title conditionally in a view rewrite field

Tags: views, 8, nodes

How can I get the field for the title of the content?

In twig I need to do this (for jssor slider) :

```
{% if field_titre_url_externe is not empty  %}
  {{ field_titre_url_externe }}
{% else %}
  {{ field_title }}
{% endif %}
```

but **field_title** is showing nothing, so what is the name of this?

EDIT :

I'm talking about the title of a node , article or content type

In my frontend, the title has the class **views-field-title**

See this image for more details (that's what I want to do):

[image]

Access the field_url_externe is not working actually... Accessing this field will solve my problem

Comment: The term "title field" is a generic, ambiguous term. It would help if you clarified and narrowed the scope of your question. Is this the "title" for a Node? The title of a view? Which template are you modifying and what are you doing? At the moment it's unclear to me what exactly you're trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct value for the `rewrite field`:

```
{% if field_url_externe is not empty  %}
  {{ field_url_externe }}
{% else %}
  {{ title }}
{% endif %}
```

You can see the available fields in the "Replace Patterns" expandable link.

[image]

Comment: This is for the plugin jssor slider, I don't think it has something to do with the theme... The twig part I'm trying to add is in the view part in backend

Comment: Twig is part of the theming system in Drupal...

Comment: Are you using the _jssor Drupal module_?, are you using a _Drupal view_? I am trying to understand better your implementation.

Comment: Yes for jssor drupal module. The part with title_prefix is not working. I'm using a view in drupal backend. This my update post for more details

Comment: Just updated the answer in a _views_ rewrite field title is the correct variable

Comment: Did you seem my update image ? {{ title }} is indeed the variable I was looking for, but how to access the order field value (as shown on my image)

Comment: Just updated the answer... Sorry, it had some wrong code from the 1st answer attempt.

Comment: I have these result, what should i do with theses patterns ?

Comment: Those are the names of the variables available to you in the _rewrite results_ area, the different fields and variations on them. The order of the fields matter. Are you getting an error? doesn't the twig snippet work?

Comment: It's working, I wasn't on the right page. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

Is title a field you made or do you mean the node title? Node title can be printed with either `{{ label }}` or `{{ node.getTitle() }}`.

Fields that you created on the node, they are rendered out as:

`{{ content.field_title }}`

Which can be checked as:

```
{% if node.field_title_external is not empty  %}
  {{ content.field_title_external }}
{% else %}
  {{ node.getTitle() }}
{% endif %}
```

You can also use `{{ label }}` instead of `{{ node.getTitle() }}`.

Comment: It's indeed showing the external link, but the title of the node is not showing

Comment: That seems impossible unless this is not shown in the context of a node? Title of _what_ node exactly? Title of the node being viewed, or title of _a referenced_ node? A different field title?

Comment: Title of the node articles (drupal) and some custom content type. The title of a drupal article and it's external link will be the same, but the link won't. If the external link is set, don't show drupal article title but show external link

Comment: Ok, you are doing this from Views, which is different than the normal theming methods.